# What are some of the good and bad aspects of this basic design?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

I made this design for a university assignment, but I am genuinely interested of this design's good and bad aspects.

The design was supposed to be an OOP design.

The system is meant to be an online store. Users can browse a catalogue of products and add them to their cart. Within the cart they can proceed to checkout and an order is created that generates an invoice and awaits a payment.

Some future me remarks:

- I don't see the purpose of the Invoice class. I'm sure the Order class can do everything that the Incoice class theoretically does.
- I think some other classes should also be able to reference the Database, for example, I think Order should add the order to the databse.
- I'm not sure why I wrapped the Payment class in "<< >>"...

[image: Class descriptions]
[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: If design is good or bad can only be found out by implementing it and seeing how it behaves in real environment. Also, design should also include behavior, which should be what drives the design.

Comment: Also, a design is good or bad largely based on how well it meets your specific requirements.  In my view, good designs are, to a certain extent, a living document; you modify the design as you find ways to improve it that more closely align with your specific needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euphoric and Robert Harvey are correct, without knowing how your application is expected to behave, we cannot judge if this schema is a good or bad implementation of that behavior. You're asking us a "find the differences" puzzle while only showing us one of two images.

That being said, if the person has three eyes in this image, I'm going to make an educated guess that the third eye is one of the differences. So I'll make a similar educated guess for your purposes. It's no a fully complete answer, but I hope it adds value for you.

---

> I don't see the purpose of the Invoice class. I'm sure the Order class can do everything that the Invoice class theoretically does.

Invoices are a summary of an order, but they are not inherently tied one-to-one. Ideally, one order generates one invoice, with the same content, but that is not always the case.

- If the customer does not pay on time, a second invoice (with the same content, or possibly with a late fee) will be sent. You will want to track each sent invoice separately, even though there is only one order here.
- If the ordered goods cannot be delivered at the same time, the order may be delivered in two stages, and an invoice sent for each stage.
- Orders could be cancelled before they get to the invoice stage

All of these are valid reasons for your diagram needing to account for having separate lifecycles on the order and invoice entities.

---

> I think some other classes should also be able to reference the Database, for example, I think Order should add the order to the databse.

Your diagram is very confused between whether it's an entity relation diagram or a dependency graph. These are two separate things, both very useful, but not when mashed together.

Everything except the `SalesReportGenerator` and `DatabaseAPI` explains how the data relates to other data sets, e.g. how an order can contain multiple products. In an ERD, there is no mention of how this data is being stored (if at all).

`SalesReportGenerator` and `DatabaseAPI` are not data relationships. They are implementations of business logic that will handle this data (in some manner).

Note, however, that `SalesReport` itself *could* valid content for an ERD, as it is a data entity which presumably refers to existing data.

---

Your orders don't refer to the customer's account (directly), they go through the cart. Why?

A cart is only used as a temporary placeholder *until* an order is made. You could conceptually think of it as an unsaved order.
While this is not always true, carts could simply be a locally tracked cookie on the user's machine, as opposed to a tracked entity in the backend. However, this very much depends, e.g. Amazon *does* in fact store your cart on their backend.

And even if you did somehow track carts and had orders refer to those carts, then why would an order still refer back to products as well? When using carts, isn't an order's product list already defined by the cart the order refers to?

Furthermore, you also claim that:

> **Order** - Made up of products

Yet your diagram shows you that a product has 0..* orders (which is the other way around). That's not the same thing a what you just described.

Think of it this way: I have made an order to buy 5 different products. How many rows are there now in each table, if we use your approach?

- The products table must logically have at least 5 different products in it. But there were no rows added here. The products already existed for me to be able to order them.
- The order table should have **1** new entry, as I made **one** order. Yet, according to your diagram, it would have *5* new entries, one for each different product I ordered. Therefore, the concept of "an order" having multiple products doesn't exist.
- The cart I used to have filled with these 5 different products still exists. But it contains pretty much the same information you can already find in the order now. So why do we have both?

The common solution here is to break down your order in two tables, `Order` and `OrderLine`.

```
                 ┌────────────┐
                 │   Order    │
                 └─────▲──────┘
                      1│
                       │
                       │*
┌───────────┐    ┌─────┴──────┐
│  Product  ◄────┤ OrderLine  │
└───────────┘1  *└────────────┘
```

Repeating the same exercise:

- The products table must logically have at least 5 different products in it. But there were no rows added here. The products already existed for me to be able to order them.
- The order table should have **1** new entry, as I made **one** order.
- That one order contains **five** different products, so **5** orderlines were created, all referring back to that same order, and each entry referring to one specific product.
- The cart can be modeled like the `OrderLine` entity, but without a parent order. This is because a cart is a unique entity of which a user always has one. You can inherently assume that all mentioned products in the cart table (for the same user ID) are part of the same cart. While it's important to remember which items were part of which order, because there can be many orders for the same user, there is only one cart per user, so the "cart lines" entity only needs to refer to a parent user, not a parent cart.
- When making an order, you effectively create an orderline for each cartline, and you create one parent order entity to keep them all together.

Comment: Thank you sir for your time and insight. I suppose an educated guess is what I was hoping for, and your remarks were very useful to me so again thank you.